# How can I recursively call a class member function via a function pointer?

Tags: c++, recursion, pointer-to-member

I'm writing a library to run certain algorithms on tree-like objects.  I have an `edge_t` class that has `const unsigned int` data members `edge_id` and `weight` that serve, respectively, as the `edge_t`'s unique identifier and the weight of the edge.

I have written `tree_t` and `subtree_t` classes in C++, both of which contain maps to pointers to `edge_t`s.  Both `tree_t` and `subtree_t` are each derived from an abstract `basic_tree_t` class that contains all the functionality that tree-like objects are supposed to have, including the following methods:

```
// returns the sum of the weights of the edge_ts below the edge_t pointed to by edge_ptr
unsigned int basic_tree_t::weight(const edge_ptr) const

// returns the number of edge_ts below the edge_t pointed to by edge_ptr
unsigned int basic_tree_t::num_descendents(const edge_ptr) const
```

I'm writing some other code in which the user inputs a `tree_t` object, and the code has to iteratively sample a `subtree_t` from it, do some calculation, sample another `subtree_t`, do more calculation, and so on.  To do the calculation the code needs to know the values of `weight` and `num_descendents` for every edge in each of these subtree.

To avoid calculating the same values repeatedly, each time I build a new subtree I'm creating `std::map<unsigned int, unsigned int> weight_map` and `std::map<unsigned int, unsigned int> num_descendents_map`, which map each `edge_id` of the subtree's edges to the values output by the respective member functions in `basic_tree_t` and then work with those.  I wrote the following functions to populate these maps:

```
void populate_weight_map(subtree_t & S, edge_ptr & e, std::map<unsigned int, unsigned int> & weight_map)
{
        weight_map.insert(std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>(e->edge_id, S.weight(e)));
        for (auto & c : *(e->children))
                if (S.contains(c))
                        populate_weight_map(S, c, weight_map);
}

void populate_num_descendents_map(subtree_t & S, edge_ptr & e, std::map<unsigned int, unsigned int> & num_descendents_map)
{
        num_descendents_map.insert(std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>(e->edge_id, S.num_descendents(e)));
        for (auto & c : *(e->children))
                if (S.contains(c))
                        populate_weight_map(S, c, num_descendents_map);
}
```

Those are largely the same function, so I thought it would make more sense to write one function that takes a pointer to the relevant `basic_tree_t` member function as a fourth argument, something like this:

```
void populate_map(subtree_t & S, edge_ptr & e, std::map<unsigned int, unsigned int> & m, unsigned int (basic_tree_t::*f)(const edge_ptr) const)
{
        m.insert(std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>(e->edge_id, (S.*f)(e)));
        for (auto & c : *(e->children))
                if (S.contains(c))
                        populate_map(S, c, m, &basic_tree_t::*f); // ERROR ON THIS LINE!
}
```

However, the compiler returns an opaque error on the last line:

```
error: expected unqualified-id
                    populate_map(S, c, m, &basic_tree_t::*f);
                                                         ^
```

What should the fourth argument to `populate map` be?

Comment: `template <typename F>` might replace member function (with generic `std::invoke`), `std::function` is possible alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`f` is already a pointer to the desired member, so just pass that:

```
populate_map(S, c, m, f);
```

`&basic_tree_t::*f` makes no sense in that context.  It looks like an attempt to *declare* a pointer to a *data* member, which isn't what you want anyway.

Comment: Non static member functions require full qualified name: `&basic_tree_t::f`.